# Docx4j missing borders of table after adding

Tags: border, docx4j

I´ve got a problem while creating a table. Heres my code:

```
Tbl projectTable = TblFactory.createTable(rows, cols, cellWidthTwips);
Tr tr = (Tr) projectTable.getContent().get(0); 
Tc tc = (Tc) tr.getContent().get(0);
tc.getContent().add( this.mainDocument.createParagraphOfText("Cell 1"));

List<Object> lines = mainDocument.getContent();
lines.add(5, projectTable);
```

The table is added at the wanted position, but without any borders.

When I use the
    `wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(projectTable);`
method, everything works just fine. The wanted table with borders.

Where is my mistake :(?

EDIT: Here two Links to images of my XML code (can't upload because I don't have enough reputation)

[XML Part 1](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/2935/so82hacg_png.htm)

[XML Part 2](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/2935/lqq5grqg_png.htm)

And here is the XML code to copy paste:

```
-<w:p w:rsidP="00CD4679" w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00CD4679" w:rsidRPr="00CD4679">-<w:pPr>-<w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr></w:pPr>-<w:r>-<w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p>-<w:tbl>-<w:tblPr><w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/><w:tblLook w:val="04A0"/></w:tblPr>-<w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="2017"/><w:gridCol w:w="1473"/><w:gridCol w:w="1451"/><w:gridCol w:w="1492"/><w:gridCol w:w="1423"/><w:gridCol w:w="1432"/></w:tblGrid>-<w:tr w:rsidR="00B94E3A" w:rsidTr="00F63A9F">-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2017" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00B94E3A" w:rsidR="00B94E3A"/>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1473" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1451" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1492" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1423" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00B94E3A" w:rsidR="00B94E3A"/>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1432" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00B94E3A" w:rsidR="00B94E3A"/>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr>-<w:tr w:rsidR="00B94E3A" w:rsidTr="00F63A9F">-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="2017" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1473" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00B94E3A" w:rsidR="00B94E3A"/>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1451" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1492" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00B94E3A" w:rsidR="00B94E3A"/>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1423" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00B94E3A" w:rsidR="00B94E3A"/>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>-<w:tc>-<w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1432" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidRDefault="00B94E3A" w:rsidR="00B94E3A"/>-<w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F63A9F" w:rsidR="00B94E3A">-<w:r><w:t>test</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc></w:tr></w:tbl><w:p w:rsidP="0081364D" w:rsidRDefault="00C46EF4" w:rsidR="00C46EF4"/>-<w:p w:rsidP="0081364D" w:rsidRDefault="00C46EF4" w:rsidR="00C46EF4" w:rsidRPr="00CD4679">-<w:pPr>-<w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr></w:pPr>-<w:r><w:t>Ende der Vorlage</w:t></w:r></w:p>-<w:sectPr w:rsidR="00C46EF4" w:rsidRPr="00CD4679" w:rsidSect="006C532E"><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:gutter="0" w:footer="708" w:header="708" w:left="1417" w:bottom="1134" w:right="1417" w:top="1417"/><w:cols w:space="708"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr>
```

Comment: What you are doing should be fine.  Please save the docx, unzip it, and post the XML for the table, plus the object before and after.  Seems like the object before or after is affecting the table in some weird way.

Comment: okey thanks! I´ve added two screenshots of my xml document, cause i´m not allowed to upload on stackoverflow yet :)

Comment: Would be better to just paste the XML into your question.  In any case, your table just needs <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/> added to w:tblPr.

Comment: Again thanks for your comment. How can I add this style inside of the programming code? :) I´ve parsed the XML code now, sry :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static void addBorders(Tbl table) 
{
    table.setTblPr(new TblPr());
    CTBorder border = new CTBorder();
    border.setColor("auto");
    border.setSz(new BigInteger("4"));
    border.setSpace(new BigInteger("0"));
    border.setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);

    TblBorders borders = new TblBorders();
    borders.setBottom(border);
    borders.setLeft(border);
    borders.setRight(border);
    borders.setTop(border);
    borders.setInsideH(border);
    borders.setInsideV(border);
    table.getTblPr().setTblBorders(borders);
}
```